# How do i add a UserControl to a VisualWebPart (sandboxed)

Tags: sandbox-solution, visual-web-part, user-controls

I have installed Visual Studio power tools so that i can add Visual Web Parts.  This all works fine, i can deploy Visual Web Parts etc.

I now want to create a UserControl in my solution which i can reuse in my Visual Web Parts, pages etc.

How do i do this?

I have tried adding a UserControl to the solution but this causes a build failure (something about control templates in sandboxed solution)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Application pages, **user controls (.ascx files)**, and localization resource (.resx) files cannot be deployed with a sandboxed solution.

[Learn more about restrictions on Sandbox solutions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg615454.aspx)

Comment: A small remark on this is that user controls are allowed in SharePoint 2013 Visual Web Parts